# Software Engineering for REST APIs

Tags: web-services, rest, uml

At my last project we designed an issue documentation system component (like a bug reporting tool) which should integrate into different Client Applications (Desktop Applications, Mobile Apps and also standalone into a Webclient). The focus was not on the Application/UI itself, but on its functional capabilities as a service. Think of it like the Google Search API, which also can be integrated in your Browser, as a widget, on your phone, and so on.

While defining functional (Use Cases) and nonfunctional requirements I came in great trouble to define them without getting UI specific, because we wanted to get a kind of service.

As a Workaround, we simply defined our requirements to fit on a standalone Webapplication plus the nonfuntional requirement that all function calls have to be done via a RESTful Service API, hoping that we won't miss any function afterwards, when using this API in an Desktop Application for example. Due to the fact, that we don't actually want a webapp in the first place, but a service, I am not very happy with this indirect way of requirement analysis, and I hope, that our developers get the point.

So my question is: How are REST APIs or Webservices designed in a way, that a developer knows what to do? Is there a UML UseCase profile for webservices for example?

Comment: Let me try to rephrase your question. Is that what you want ask? : How should a RESTful API be specified in order to allow developers to implement it? What specification artifacts should be used for such purpose?

Comment: Thats exactly what I want to know. As a governmental organization, we often have to specify service APIs for public calls. As I already explained we often do not get what we want, and developers often have problems implementing what we specify. Keep in mind, that we have to specify Requirements, not Design, so I am primarly focusing on requirement analysis (Use Case, User Story, Basic Object Model, Activities)

Comment: Jürgen, the problem here is that you are trying to specify a technological artifact (the design of a RESTful API) in requerement analysis. For the sake of requirement analysis, a non-functional requirement would state that there are a frontend and a backend coupled by a RESTful API. You cannot go further without designing the API. Right?

Comment: I get the point, but let me give you another example of my work. As a governmental data provider, we have to provide Open Data interfaces. By its paradigm these often have to be RESTful. In requirement analysis we focus on the data and information that should be provided. How can I guarantee that the software which will be delivered is worthy for the RESTful oriented Open Data Community, and not a simple website that just "shows" the data?

Comment: HI, @JürgenZornig, did  you find something interesting since you ask the question? i having the same issue to do a requirement analysis of a system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Do not Forget : Use cases are just "half of the whole story"**

You will have **non-functional** requirements also.You can not capture every important detail with use cases.

**Then Ask Yourself : Are Use Cases Right For Me?**

Use Cases are generally good for "interactive systems":  systems that has interaction with user.They are good for capturing "functional" requirements.

> Use Cases are not good for some systems. Be open-minded. While writing
>   your use cases, you see that this does not capture what you want or does not add
>   any value *try-start with*  alternative tecniques such as just plain
>   Feature List.

**Find The Root Cause**

Ask yourself "Why I came in great trouble to define my reqirements without getting UI specific details"?

**Pick Your Battles :** Quality Scenarious + Arhitectural Factor Table

Identify your architecturally significiant requirements. One good way to define them is "Quality Scenarious":

> Quality Scenarios are short statements of the form [stimulus]
>   [measurable response]

For example: When a new bug report entered to the Bug System[stimulus],it will sended to the bug owner mobile phone within 5 minute under X conditions.[measurable response]

Then can create a Architectural Factor Table with Quality Scenarious

> Architectural Factor Table is a tool that help you to understand the
>   influence of factors, priorities and variability.

Here is a sample Factor Table from Craig Larman book: Applying UML and Patterns

[image]

**"Guarantee that the software do what you want"...**

So write your test first...Or create "executable" specifications...
And communicate...

**Finally**

There is nothing like Software Engineering for REST APIs.:-)

Comment: Thanks for giving me advice for improvement. I will try to apply factor tables and executeable test specifications to my future projects and I think that could help a lot

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the definition of [software requirements specification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_Requirements_Specification), you can specify a RESTful API as a technical requirement in the perspective of the product use such as Software Interfaces  (i.e. Overall description, Product perspective, Software interfaces). This is not a functional requirement. It is only a technical requirement of your project.

There are no UML Use Case profile because UseCase intends to specify functional requirements. You can specify the interaction of users accessing your system through the RESTful API considering the functional access and data exchange in a regular Use Case.

All the characteristics required from the expected RESTful API should be specified as a technical requirement (i.e. Specific requirements, [External interface requirements](http://isg.inesc-id.pt/REBox/WiegersTemplate@17.aspx?page=4ExternalInterfaceRequirements)). The developer knows what to do considering all requirements of the application.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the ebook, seems to be a good resource